# How to delete specific words from a sentence in text file?

Tags: python, data-processing

I have two text files. The 1st file contains English sentences and 2nd file contains a number of English words (vocabulary). I want to remove those words from the sentences in the 1st file which are not present in the vocabulary and then to save the processed text back into the 1st file.

I wrote the code from which I am able to get those sentences which contains the words that are not available in our 2nd file (vocabulary).

Here is my code:

```
s = open('eng.txt').readlines()

for i in s:

print(i)

for word in i.split(' '):
    print(word)
    if word in open("vocab30000.txt").read():
        print("Word exist in vocab")
    else:

        #print("I:", i)
        print("Word does not exist")
        #search_in_file_func(i)
        print("I:", i)
        file1 = open("MyFile.txt","a+") 
        if i in file1:
            print("Sentence already exist")
        else:
            file1.write(i)
```

However, I am not able to remove those words.

Comment: How big are your files? What is the format of the second file (one word per line, comma-separated, etc.?)

Comment: arg you're going to read the file as many times as there are words in your sentence. `if word in open("vocab30000.txt").read():` : create a word set instead in memory and check.: do that once: `word_set = {x for line in file_handle for x in line.split()`  where `file_handle` yields the result of `open`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good to see that nice approach of "create a word set instead in memory and check" !

Comment: @gmds My 1st file contains around 1.2 lakh English sentences and 2nd file contains 1.8 lakh English words separated by new line (one word per line).

Comment: @Sandeep English numbers would be good! Anyway, check my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open('vocab30000.txt') as f:
    vocabulary = set(word.strip() for word in f.readlines())

with open('eng.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = [line.strip().split(' ') for line in f.readlines()]
    removed = [[word for word in line if word in vocabulary] for line in data]
    result = '\n'.join(' '.join(word for word in line) for line in removed)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(result)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: this code not solve my problem. Suppose eng.txt contain sentence "I live in mumbai" and vocab.txt contains words (I, live, in) separated by new line. So I want output only "I live in" in my eng.txt file. I want to remove "mumbai" word from my sentence because it is not available in my vocab.txt.

Comment: @Sandeep changed something, try again.

Comment: thanks for your  quick response. This code works but  it also remove the last word from each sentence because last word contains \n like this ['Network', 'Options\n'] whereas Options word is available in my vocab30000.txt. I tried [x.replace('\n', '') for x in data] but it could not solve my problem. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Sandeep try again now; I realised I called `strip` on the vocabulary to solve this problem but forgot to do the same thing on the data.

Comment: this code is not separating the '.' or ',' from the word. when I run this code for single sentence and print data variable, I got this type of output: ['Non-Network', 'open,', 'Reimbursement.'] but I need output like this: ['Non-Network', 'open', ',', 'Reimbursement', '.']. What should I change in this code to get this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Read the two files

with open('vocab30000.txt') as f:
    vocabulary = f.readlines()

with open('eng.txt', 'r+') as f:
    eng = f.readlines()

vocab_sentences = [i.split(" ") for i in vocabulary]
eng = [i.split(" ") for i in eng]

cleaned_sentences = []
# loop over the sentences and exclude words in eng
for sent in vocab_sentences:
    cleaned_sentences.append(" ".join([i for i in sent if i not in eng]))
#write the file
with open('vocab30000.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(cleaned_sentences)
```

Comment: I ran this code but this code is not working as I want. I want to delete a new word from my eng.txt which contains the sentences and save this file as the same name eng.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. I tried not to use any loops to save your runtime if you have larger files.

```
import re

with open('eng.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
s_copy = s

punctuation = [".","\"",",","-","(",")","[","]"]

pattern = re.compile("\\b("+"|".join(punctuation)+")\\W", re.I)
s_copy = pattern.sub(" ", s_copy)
s_copy = s_copy.replace("\"","")
s_words = s_copy.split(" ")

with open('vocab30000.txt', 'r') as f:
    check_words = f.read()

remove_words = list(set(s_words) - set(check_words))

pattern = re.compile("\\b("+"|".join(remove_words[1:])+")\\W", re.I)
pattern.sub("", s)
```